# Dependencies in the pom file of a library, not coming over as a transient dependency in the parent project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a simple springboot application where I am autowiring up a spring based java library. For some reason just one maven dependency (among a dozen) listed in the library's pom file is not getting pulled in when I build the springboot application and it fails at runtime with

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.Client
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Adding this in the springboot application's pom gets rid of the error

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do I troubleshoot/fix this? I don't want to add this in the springboot application's pom when it is already listed in the library applications pom.

Update:
I have this in the library's pom

```
....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Are they really listed as dependendies or are they rather in a `dependencyManagement` section?\

Comment: 1. You have checked that the above updated section is not inside `<dependencyManagement>`? 2. Please look at the dependency tree ( `mvn dependency:tree`)

Comment: It did not show up in mvn dependency:tree. Then I realized I added the library as a jar reference in intellij and it did not come thru maven. That's why the transitive dependencies did not get pulled in.